# SSIS and SharePoint List Source how to handle erros?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ssis, dataflow

How can I handle errors with "SharePoint List Source", in a Integration Services Data Flow?

I want to test if a site URL exist in Sharepoint, if not I want to handle the error.

I am using SharePoint 2010, Integration Services with Visual Studio 2008.